# redirect on form submit

Tags: php, forms

I am new to php. I have tried the following code to redirect the page when sign In button is clicked, but it is not happening. please help me editing the code. probably, there is an error in header() function. Have I used the header() function correctly?

```
<body>
<?php
  $emailErr = $passwordErr = "";
  $email = $password = "";

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
          $emailErr = "*Email is required";
      } else {
          $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
          // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
           if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
               $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
           }
      }

      if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
          $passwordErr = "*Password is required";
      } else {
         $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
      }
   }

function test_input($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

include("signInform.php");
if($_POST["sign"])
{
  header('Location:signInform.php');
}
?>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<h1>WELCOME</h1>
<h2>Please, Register Yourself!</h2>
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 

<label>E-mail:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="email"/>
<span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br />

<label>Password:</label><br />
<input type="password" name="password"/>
<span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Register"/><br/>

<p>If already a user, Sign in! </p>
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="sign"/><br/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: use `exit();` after `header()`

Comment: You must put your code starting of the document. because header will throw warning "header already sent" when any printed output before header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@ob_start();` top of the page,

```
if (isset($_POST["sign"])) {
    header('Location:signInform.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove following line.

```
include("signInform.php");
```

and put header function like below.

```
header('location:signInform.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is header already send.You can avoid this issue by using `ob_start()`.Try like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$emailErr = $passwordErr = "";
$email = $password = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

if (empty($_POST["email"]))
{
$emailErr = "*Email is required";}
else
{
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
// check if e-mail address syntax is valid
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
{
$emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
}

if (empty($_POST["password"]))
{$passwordErr = "*Password is required";}
else
{$password = test_input($_POST["password"]);}
}

function test_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
include("signInform.php");
if($_POST["sign"])
{
header('Location:signInform.php');
exit();
    }
?>

<body>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<h1>WELCOME</h1>
<h2>Please, Register Yourself!</h2>
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 

<label>E-mail:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="email"/>
<span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br />

<label>Password:</label><br />
<input type="password" name="password"/>
<span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Register"/><br/>

<p>If already a user, Sign in! </p>
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="sign"/><br/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use--- echo '<script> location.href="signInform.php";</script>';
instead of  header('Location:signInform.php');

replace if($_POST["sign"])
{
  header('Location:signInform.php');
}
to
if($_POST["sign"])
{
echo '<script> location.href="signInform.php";</script>';
}

and why did you include include("signInform.php"); this line that's why showing error already sent.
```